# test result chart with custom test case priority

Tags: tfs

For our test cases, we use custom priorities. The results of those test cases are shown in a test case result chart [(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHKqB.png). The problem is that the chart does not get the custom priorities of our test cases. Is there a way to configure the charts or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test result chart , you could  use test results charts to track how your testing is going. Choose from a fixed set of **pre-populated** fields related to results.

[image]

[image]

If you want to group by a **custom field**, suggest you to use a  [**query-based chart**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/charts?view=vsts#create-a-query-based-chart)

> If you don't see the field you want in the Group by drop-down list,
>   **add the field as a column to the query** and save the query. You can group by any field except date-time and free-form text fields. For
>   example:
>
> - To group by iterations, include the Iteration Path in the query or    column options
> - To group by team, include the Area Path or Node Name in the query or    column options
> - To group by a custom field, include it in a query clause or column    options

Comment: Thank you for giving me the right direction with query based charts :-)